# Aerospike ACID - How to know the final result of the transaction on timeouts?

Tags: database, nosql, timeout, aerospike, acid

I'm new to Aerospike.

I would like to know that in all possible timeout scenarios, as stated in this link:

https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/understanding-timeout-and-retry-policies/2852

> 1. Client can’t connect by specified timeout (timeout=). Timeout of zero
>      means that there is no timeout set.
> 2. Client does not receive response by specified timeout (timeout=).
> 3. Server times out the transaction during it’s own processing (default
>      of 1 second if client doesn’t specify timeout). To investigate this,
>      confirm that the server transaction latencies are not the bottleneck.
> 4. Client times out after M iterations of retries when there was no error
>      due to a failed node or a failed connection.
> 5. Client can’t obtain a valid node after N retries (where retries are
>      set from your client).
> 6. Client can’t obtain a valid connection after X retries. The retry
>      count is usually the limiting factor, not the timeout value. The
>      reasoning is that if you can’t get a connection after R retries, you
>      never will, so just timeout early.

Of all timeout scenarios mentioned, under which circumstances could I be absolute certain that the final result of the transaction is FAILED?

Does Aerospike offer anything i.e. to rollback the transaction if the client does not respond?

In the worst case, If I could’t be certain about the final result, how would I be able to know for certain about the final state of the transaction?

Many thanks in advance.

***Edit:*** 
***We came up with a temporary solution:***

Keep a map of [generation -> value read] for that record (maybe a background thread constantly reading the record etc.) and then on timeouts, we would periodically check the map (key = the generation expected) to see if the true written value is actually the one put to the map. If they are the same, it means the write succeeded, otherwise it means the write failed.

Do you guys think it's necessary to do this? Or is there other way?

Comment: Also posted at https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/understanding-timeout-and-retry-policies/2852/2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent clients will provide an extra flag on timeouts, called "in doubt". If false, you are certain the transaction did not succeed (client couldn't even connect to the node so it couldn't have sent the transaction). If true, then there is still an uncertainty as the client would have sent the transaction but wouldn't know if it had reached the cluster or not.

You may also consider looking at Aerospike's [Strong Consistency](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/consistency.html) feature which could help your use case.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I've found the "in doubt" field. This would narrow down the problem significantly. Regarding the Strong Consistency, I'm on the community version so that isn't provided. I'll look into it later. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

First, timeouts are not the only error you should be concerned with. Newer clients have an '[inDoubt](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/AerospikeException.html#getInDoubt())' flag associated with errors that will indicate that the write may or may not have applied.

There isn't a built-in way of resolving an in-doubt transaction to a definitive answer and if the network is partitioned, there isn't a way in AP to rigorously resolve in-doubt transactions. Rigorous methods do exist for '[Strong Consistency](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration#strong-consistency)' mode, the same methods can be used to handle common AP scenarios but they will fail under partition.

The method I have used is as follows:

1. Each record will need a list bin, the list bin will contain the last N transaction ids.

   - For my use case, I gave each client an unique 2 byte identifier - each client thread a unique 2 byte identifier - and each client thread had a 4 byte counter. So a particular transaction-id would look like would mask an 8 byte identifier from the 2 ids and counter.
2. * Read the records metadata with the [getHeader](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/Operation.html#getHeader()) api - this avoids reading the records bins from storage.

   - Note - my use case wasn't an increment so I actually had to read the record and write with a generation check. This pattern should be more efficient for a counter use case.
3. Write the record using operate and [gen-equal](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/GenerationPolicy.html#EXPECT_GEN_EQUAL) to the read generation with the these operations: increment the integer bin, [prepend to the list](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list.html#list-apis)  of txns, and [trim](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list.html#list-apis) the list of txns. You will prepend you transaction-id to your txns list and then trim the list to the max size of the list you selected.

   - N needs to be large enough such that a record can be sure to have enough time to verify its transaction given the contention on the key. N will affect the stored size of the record so choosing too big will cost disk resource and choosing too small will render the algorithm ineffective.
4. If the transaction is successful then you are done.
5. If the transaction is 'inDoubt' then read the key and check the txns list for your transaction-id. If present then your transaction 'definitely succeeded'.
6. If your transaction-id isn't in txns, repeat step 3 with the generation returned from the read in step 5.
7. Return to step 3 - with the exception that on step 5 a 'generation error' would also need to be considered 'in-doubt' since it may have been the previous attempt that finally applied.

Also consider that reading the record in step 5 and not finding the transaction-id in txns does not ensure that the transaction 'definitely failed'. If you wanted to leave the record unchanged but have a 'definitely failed' semantic you would need to  have observed the generation move past the previous write's gen-check policy. If it hasn't you could replace the operation in step 6 with a touch - if it succeeds then the initial write 'definitely failed' and if you get a generation-error you will need to check if you raced the application of the initial transaction initial write may now have 'definitely succeeded'.

Again, with 'Strong Consistency' the mentions of 'definitely succeeded' and 'definitely failed' are accurate statements, but in AP these statements have failure modes (especially around network partitions).